# C# & ASP.NET MVC : temporarily bind data to model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

but in my controller I want to add a temporary binding of data just to be passed once to a View such that:

```
Person.temp = new string();
```

and in each `Person` object in my controller I can add a unique `Person.temp` before it is sent to its view:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
     Person per = new Person();
     per.temp = "example" + i;
     per.PersonId = i;
     per.Email = "555example@stack.co";
     listofPersons.Add(per)
}

return(listofPersons)
```

Comment: `class PersonWithTemp : Person { public string Temp { get; set; } }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Person
 {

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Temp {get;set;}

 }
```

Have your tried marking it as NotMapped ?